# Removing items from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python and I'm wondering, how I would go about removing items from a list. Say I have the list:

```
a=[(102,12,0),(123,12,0),(124,12,1)]
```

I would like to remove the items that have a 0 at the end, so my list would end up like:

```
a = [(124,12,1)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here:

```
a = [i for i in a if i[-1] != 0] #list comprehension (1 line) method.
```

"normal" way to do without list comprehension when the parent list is also destination list.

```
tmp = []
for i in a:
    if i[-1] != 0:
        tmp.append(i)
a = tmp
```

in action:

```
>>> a=[(102,12,0),(123,12,0),(124,12,1)]
>>> a = [i for i in a if i[-1] != 0]
>>> a
[(124, 12, 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: You might want to explain [list comprehensions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: You can also use `for i in a.copy(): \n if i[-1] == 0: \n a.remove(i)`

Comment: @Mahi there are numerous ways to solve this particular type of question, the proper way depends on the list's data structure, (in this case, a list - but it could be a dict, or a hashlibrary or etc etc.) how expensive it is to remove, or add, or create, or iterate. also, are we removing more than we would be adding? there is no 'generic best' solution, but list-comprehension does a pretty good job, and is generic enough and simple enough to be very efficient in most cases. but thanks for the extra options.

Comment: @InbarRose Yes, I totally agree with list comprehension being the best solution! But for the "normal" way, I prefer using `.copy() & .remove()` to `tmp & .append()`. Just giving out my opinion :)

Comment: @Mahi in that case, why not `iteritems` and remove? (`for i in iter(a): \n if i[-1] == 0: \n a.remove(i)`)

Comment: Removing isn't a great way of doing it as it's much more computationally complex. Removing an item from a list involves going through the list to find the item, so looping and removing involves going over the list one time, plus one time for each removal, while making a new list involves only one loop (and the list comprehension likewise, except even faster as the loop is c-side).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

`val[-1]` would give you tuples with 0 at the end, assuming `val` is the variable used while iterating.

So, your code would be something like this:

```
a = [val for val in a if val[-1]]
```

Comment: Note that if the tuples can contain non-numeric elements, this will remove things like `None` or empty collections (anything that evaluates to `False`).

Answer (score 1):

Not as awesome as a one liner list comprehension but still do the trick :).

```
b = tuple
for tple in a:
    b = b + tple
result = tuple
for val in set(b):
    if val % 10 != 0:
        result = result + (val,)
```